# Google Chrome keeps crashing in Ubuntu 18.04. Here is the error

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, crash

```
$ google-chrome-stable
[6133:6163:1005/193134.788038:ERROR:media_history_store.cc(363)] Failed to create or update the media history store.
[6170:6170:1005/193134.809003:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
--2020-10-05 19:32:41--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.166.174, 2404:6800:4009:80e::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.166.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’


     0KCrash dump id:   47c50870b0a33a62 
                                                     2.19M=0s

Bus error (core dumped)
[1005/193250.042909:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

Comment: Are you running it with `sudo`? Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are running Chrome with `sudo`. Browsers are not supposet to be run as root.